# Write logic code inside tag

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to have a switch case statement inside Step tag to get a correct format message base on step number, but it always prompt error there.

The error says:

> [ts] Expression expected

```
export const MainBoxHeader = props => (
  <Row style={{ marginBottom: 12 }} gutter={100}>
    <Col span={8}>
      <BackButton
        style={{ visibility: props.backButtonIsHidden ? 'hidden' : 'visible' }}
        onClick={props.onClickBack}
      >
        <FormattedMessage id="back" />
      </BackButton>
    </Col>
    <Col span={8}>
      <Step>
        <FormattedMessage id={`SE-196.PopUp${(props.step)}.Step`} />
      </Step>
    </Col>
    <Col span={8}>
      <ColorBtn color="purple" onClick={props.onClickNext}>
        <FormattedMessage id="continue" />
      </ColorBtn>
    </Col>
  </Row>
);
```

Comment: Please elaborate further on your question. What is it you're trying to to? What is the error? Does this switch need to be inside the `Step` component or the `MainBoxHeader` component?

Comment: Hi @DominikJanković, I update the picture, I think it would be easy to understand what I need.

Comment: Please do not supply only images of code please post the actual code in the answer in addition to an image if relevant

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46593006/9454740

Comment: Why do you have an image instead of plain text? It's code.

Comment: I can not paste it, tags disappear when I paste.

Comment: @Khuong indent 4 spaces and paste

Comment: Updated. It's the code.

Comment: Is it just me or the content of the code now looks different from the image posted before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below syntax

```
<Step>
    {(() => {
        switch(...) {}
    })()}
</Step>
```

Here you need to return the value.

**OR**

You can use

```
renderSwitch(param) {
  switch(param) {
    case 'foo':
      return 'bar';
    default:
      return 'foo';
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <Step>
      {this.renderSwitch(param)}
     </Step> 
  );
}
```

Here you can use a function where you can write the switch case and use it in your render statement

Comment: This is correct but you should explain is that the cases need to use `return` instead of `break` as well

Comment: @AluanHaddad can you check my answer now

Comment: Thanks, but it says undefined when I get props.step, how to cast it as number?

Comment: can you console your pops ?

Comment: It gives me "PopUpundefined.Step"

Comment: i think you don't have Step key inside your props

Comment: i think you are not passing Step from your parent component

Comment: @SangramBadi, yes, you're right. Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: happy to help you. i am upvoting you

Answer (score 2):

Sangram's soultion will work, but you could use template literals and do away with the switch alltogether. Or extract the switch into a function and reference it in your functional component - both solutions would, IMHO, be cleaner.

For example:

```
export const MainBoxHeader = props => (
  // ...
  <Step>
    <FormattedMessage id={`PopUp${props.step}.Step`} />
  </Step>
  // ...
)
```

Or

```
const getFormattedMessage = step => (
  switch (step) {
    case 1:
      return <FormattedMessage ... />
  }
)

export const MainBoxHeader = props => (
  // ...
  <Step>
    {getFormattedMessage(props.step)}
  </Step>
  // ...
)
```

Or maybe think about if that logic would be better suited for the step component itself, where you would pass Step a prop such as `<Step stepId={props.step} />` and handle the rendering logic inside `Step` itself. Of course, you might have a valid reason not to to that and could use any of the above solutions instead.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks, but it says undefined when I get props.step, how to cast it as number?

Comment: Did you pass a `step` prop to `MainBoxHeader`?

Comment: yes I pass step equal to 1.

Comment: Update your question with the component that renders `MainBoxHeader` so we can see what's going on exactly. If you're passing everything correctly, `step` shouldn't be undefined in your functional component's `props`.

Answer (score 1):

Put the logic outside the return JSX and store the result to a local variable, and then embed it in the return JSX.

```
var stepNode = null; // some sensible default in case of unexpected input; depends on what you want to happen in your situation.

if (props.step == 1) {
    stepNode = <Something ...>
} else if (props.step == 2) {
    stepNode = <Something-Else ....>
}
return (<TheJSX>
            ....
                <Div> { stepNode } </Div>
            .....
       </TheJSX>);
```

**EDIT:**

Regarding the default value, you have to consider what should happen if the input does not match what you expect, e.g. say `props.step` is set to 4.

I believe React just ignores `null` values, but I could be mistaken. Depending on your situation, you might want to log an error or show something entirely different.

Comment: The use of `null` is pointless and it prevents the type system from providing definite assignment errors in this case because the variable always has a value. This wasn't doesn't really answer the question and it's poorly formatted

Comment: null is not pointless because his switch statement only covers values 1 and 2; what if `props.step` has the value 34?

Comment: it would be better to not specify an initial value and to handle the absence explicitly. Specifically, what I'm objecting to is the use of an initial assignment prevents the compiler from doing definitely assignment analysis. `let stepNode`  is correct

Comment: The compiler will tell you not all paths assign a value, so you should fix it by assigning some default sensible value when you see unexpected input.

Comment: The accepted answer, for example, calls a function, but that function will just return `undefined` in the case of unexpected values. How is that any better?

Comment: correct, but that whole point is that it won't tell you _because_ you gave it a default.

Comment: So when it tells you, what do you do? Giving a default is the _fix_ for the warning you want the compiler to show.

Comment: Regarding `undefined`, I think it is preferable to `null` because the former is always a possibility while the latter introduces an additional possible type

Comment: Uhm, no, it's not preferable, I don't even know what you could possibly be thinking. Plus, the point of the answer is to give an example, because I don't know the context in which the OP is working in.

Comment: I'll remove my down vote because the difference is somewhat stylistic but I dislike this approach

Comment: Thanks. I dislike many approaches people take but I don't try to enforce my approach. What matters is whether the code works or not.

Comment: Is there any ESLint rule to detect this?