# how to render input fields on page load at runtime based upon json in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have below array of objects as sample input. I have this object available on page load of component.

I need to iterate on it and then fetch its Label Name,its input type and text associated to it.

Say suppose for first objet, I need to show label and its input type is dropdown and its text in one row, then go to second object show its lable text, its input type is textbox and then text on second row and so on for all other objects.

It should happen on run time when page is loading. I am not sure how to do it.

I just need to render it on page load. So I know that I need to write that code in `componentDidMount()` method but how to render is not sure.

While I am looking for sample code but approach to resolve it will also help me to solve it on my own. Thanks in advance.

```
[
    {

        "LABEL_NAME": "Purpose",
        "LABEL_TYPE": "STANDARD_LABEL",
        "WIDGET_TYPE": "NARROW_DROPDOWN",
        "TEXT": "Abc"
    },
    {
        "LABEL_NAME": "Sub-purpose",
        "LABEL_TYPE": "STANDARD_LABEL",
        "WIDGET_TYPE": "Textbox",
        "HELP_TEXT": "pqr"
    },   
    {
        "LABEL_NAME": "Date",
        "LABEL_TYPE": "STANDARD_LABEL",
        "WIDGET_TYPE": "DATE_FIELD",
        "HELP_TEXT": null
    }
]
```

Comment: Take a look at this
https://codesandbox.io/s/axios-playground-j6cph.

A different approach would be to create an API to that returns your list of labels instead of returning on page load.
You can call this API from componentDidMount method and add it to your state.once the data is received. Then populate the input fileds using this data.

Comment: I had a look there. But it is displaying a data in list format, I need to display like Lable Name --> Its input type say Textbox/Dropdown --> Text and then on second row continues for second object,

Comment: Check this now. I have update it https://codesandbox.io/s/axios-playground-j6cph.
I think that should give you an idea how it can be done.

Comment: @AbhilashChelankara I am using your code. Geting positive progres. Thanks a billion for this.

Comment: glad that it helped you. Would be great if you could  upvote my comments.

Comment: I have blow code.  <li>
                <b>{LABEL_NAME == "Undefined" ? "" : LABEL_NAME }</b> :  { WIDGET_TYPE = "NARROW_DROPDOWN"  ? <Dropdown className =""></Dropdown> : ""
              </li>  How can I check the switch case in widget type case. I want to make controls based upon its type. Like dropdown or textbox or any other.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592833/how-to-use-switch-statement-inside-a-react-component This shows a lot of ways to do it

Comment: @AbhilashChelankara Its done. Thank you very very very much.