# React Flagging a Calculation based on props value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle, setstate

I have a component where i make an order estimation calculation ( a multiplication of quantity for his price ) in two cases

1) In the lifecycle method

```
componentDidMount(){
  if (this.props.isRestarted) {
    this.setState({
          orderEstimation: this.props.formData.valNominal * this.props.formData.priceLimit,
   })
}
```

2) In an Event

```
<FormAmountField
    label={}
    placeholder={}
    value={this.state.price}
    onChangeText={(value) => {
    this.setState({
        price: value,
        orderEstimation: parseFloat(value) * parseFloat(this.state.quantity)
    })
}}
```

As you can see in both cases: `orderEstimation: parseFloat(value) * parseFloat(this.state.quantity)`

I have a case when `this.props.selectedTitleDetails.exchangeHost == "THIS_TEXT"` i want the  the calculation changing `parseFloat(value) * parseFloat(this.state.quantity) / 100`

How can i apply this change in both cases? in the life cycle and the method?

Comment: Why don't you use a function with Switch cases in it.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592833/how-to-use-switch-statement-inside-a-react-component/46593006)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable of state to mark - `exchangeValue`. Example:

```
constructor() {
    this.state = {
        exchangeValue: 1
    }
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
     if (prevProps.selectedTitleDetails.exchangeHost !== this.props.selectedTitleDetails.exchangeHost 
         && this.props.selectedTitleDetails.exchangeHost === 'THIS_TEXT') {
          this.setState({
               exchangeValue: 100
          })
     }
}
```

Then you add `this.state.exchangeValue` into the your calculation

```
componentDidMount(){
  if (this.props.isRestarted) {
    this.setState({
          orderEstimation: this.props.formData.valNominal * this.props.formData.priceLimit / this.state.exchangeValue,
   })
}
```

And

```
onChangeText={(value) => {
    this.setState({
        price: value,
        orderEstimation: parseFloat(value) * parseFloat(this.state.quantity) / this.state.exchangeValue
    })
}}
```