# Conditional rendering of nested components based on condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

Unsure how to write the following nested if/else as a nested ternary within a React app, i.e.

```
if (jobId === 1) {
  if (activeFlag === 1) {
    <RenderA />
  } else if (activeFlag === 2) {
    <RenderB />
  } else if (activeFlag === 3) {
    <RenderC />
  }
}
```

I tried:

```
{
 (jobId === 1) ?
    (activeFlag === 1) ? (<RenderA />) : (activeFlag === 2) ? (<RenderB />) 
}
```

Unsure if I am on the right track?

Comment: You can use ternary operator if you have if else condition. From what I see here, you dont render anything if jobId is other than 1 and similarly if activeFlag has value other than 1,2,3

Comment: Consider putting this logic in its own function or component, and then returning the JSX you want to render. You can then call this function, or use it as a component

Comment: You could create an object literal: `const map = { 1: RenderA, 2: RenderB, etc }` and then get the component based on activeFlag like `const component = map[activeFlag]`. If not found, return null

Comment: I was writing test cases for my solution when the question got marked as a duplicate, so I posted it [as an answer to the "primary" question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67432973/8223070). (I don't claim that it's the best way to handle rendering in react, but it answers the question you asked instead of a similar question.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this `jobId === 1 ? activeFlag === 1 ? <RenderA /> : activeFlag === 2 ? <RenderB /> : activeFlag === 3 && <RenderC /> : ""`

Comment: This doesn't check for `jobId === 1` for `RenderB` and `RenderC`

Comment: @adiga are you sure this will not work? If yes then please check this link https://replit.com/@sahilardeshna/AdmirablePitifulTrial#index.js

Comment: For `jobId = 2, activeFlag = 2`, OP's code doesn't return anything because of the first `if (jobId === 1)` check. But, your code will return `RenderB` because you only have `jobId === 1` check for  `RenderA`

Comment: @adiga yes you are right, answer updated. Thanks

Comment: It works now. But, OP's code is easily understandable while your code with nested `?:` is unreadable. So, there is no reason to use this code.

Comment: Yes, That's true. Ternary is complicated when there are more than a condition.

Comment: `a ? b : c ? d : e` is fine because the conditions execute in that order. But, `a ? b ? c : d : e` works like `a ? (b ? c : d) : e`. You'd need something like [astexplorer](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/1ea1c3d52a085581150a72ed1f8c72a2/54c31dd5c9534fb1aa1fa5e728282d1649d9a867) to understand the execution order.

Comment: @adiga i get that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A more readable solution could be create an inline render function as

```
const renderThisThing = () => {
  if (jobId !== 1) {
    return null
  }

  if (activeFlag === 1) {
    return <RenderA />
  }

  if (activeFlag === 2) {
    return <RenderB />
  }

  if (activeFlag === 3) {
    return <RenderC />
  }

  return null
}


const elementToIncludeInTheJSX = renderThisThing()
```

and then put `{elementToIncludeInTheJSX}` in the place you want to render the component. You can inline this function in the body of your component, or make it a real React component, and pass `jobId` and `activeFlag` as props.

```
function ComplexRenderComponent({ jobId, activeFlag }) {
  if (jobId !== 1) {
    return null
  }

  if (activeFlag === 1) {
    return <RenderA />
  }

  if (activeFlag === 2) {
    return <RenderB />
  }

  if (activeFlag === 3) {
    return <RenderC />
  }

  return null
}
```

and you use it as `<ComplexRenderComponent jobId={jobId} activeFlag={activeFlag} />` in your component.