# React conditional rendering and return the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Need a little guidance with conditional rendering in react

```
class Car extends React.Component {
id = '123456'

  render() {

   if("id".includes("1") === true){

    return <h2>$$${id}</h2>;

}
else{
         return <h2>{id}</h2>;
  }
}
```

For rendering $$$ for certain condition , apart from using if else and rendering
is there any way to conditionally render ???
a better way and the return can be quite long in big applications
is there a way to write conditional and return the value according to it?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear so do well to add some clarity if my answer is not satisfactory.

When you want to conditionally render in react you can use the short-circuiting property of the && operator.

For example:

```
(false && "Logged In")
//Logged In
```

So using this idea, you can do the same for components

```
function App(props) {
    let element
    if(props.loggedIn) {
        element = <div>Logged In</div>
    } else {
        element = <div>Not Logged In</div>
    }
    return element
}
```

simply becomes

```
function App(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                props.loggedIn && 
                <h3>You're logged in as {props.data.username}</h3>
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: its a different perspective, thanks for taking time and explaining @NGY

Answer (score 1):

There's a variety of ways to do conditional rendering. Here is one example with a ternary operator for simple cases:

```
    render() {
         return <h2>{id.includes("1") ? "$$$" : ""}{id}</h2>
    }
```

You can also look into using a [switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592833/how-to-use-switch-statement-inside-a-react-component), where you move the conditional logic outside of the render function.

Comment: if id is string/number , will includes still work ?

Comment: `includes` works with strings, so you can convert `id` to a string if it isn't already with `String(id)`