# Can I do a switch statement inside a return statement in react

Tags: reactjs, switch-statement

```
const Component = () => {
   let x = 1
   
   switch(x) {
   case 1: 
      return (
         <Component1 /> 
         <Component2 /> 
      )
   case 2: 
      return (
         <Component1 /> 
         <Component3 /> 
      )
   }
}
```

In the above code, in `case 1`, `Component1` and `Component2` are rendered while in `case 2`, `Component1` and `Component3` are rendered.

Is there a way to minimize repeated code by using a `switch` statement inside a single return statment eg.

```
const Component = () => {
   let x = 1
   
return (
   <Component1 /> 

   switch(x) {
   case 1: 
       <Component2 /> 
   case 2: 
       <Component3 />   
   }
}
```

Comment: To my knowledge, Functions returning Components must return a _single_ object: so if you want to return multiple Component objects (incl JSX) then you need to either wrap them in _another_ outer Component - or return a JS array of components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sort-of.

In React, functions that return Components must always return a *single* object: so if you want to return multiple Component objects (incl JSX) then you need to either wrap them in another outer Component - or return a JS array of components.

So that means if you want to return "`Component1`-and-`Component2` **OR** `Component1`-and-`Component3`" then you should return an array, as either...:

`[ <Component1/>, <Component2/> ]` ...or `[ <Component1/>, <Component3/> ]`

...[while the `switch` block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) in JavaScript *itself* is a statement and not an expression, JavaScript already has an expression equivalent: the ternary operator `?:`, it's just slightly messier to deal with.

...but that means you can return a JS array literal with `Component2` or `Component3` as the last element, chosen with the `?:` operator, like so:

```
const Component = () => {
    let x = 1
   
    return [
        // Element 0:
        <Component1 />,
        // Element 1:
        ( x === 1 ) ? <Component2 /> :
        ( x === 2 ) ? <Component3 /> :
        throw new Error( "This should never happen." )
    ];
}
```

Though if you *know* that `x` will **always** only ever be `1` or `2` then ([in addition to using a custom `type` for `x` instead of `number`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494689/is-it-possible-to-restrict-number-to-a-certain-range)) then you can do just this:

```
const Component = () => {
    let x = 1
   
    return [
        <Component1 />,
        ( x === 1 ) ? <Component2 /> : <Component3 />
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you NEED to use switch statement inside?
You could as easily just use if else - if the conditions are not many.

You essentially can just make the switch a separate component just to do the logic instead on inside return.

Or you can look at answers here: [How to use switch statement inside a React component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592833/how-to-use-switch-statement-inside-a-react-component)

Most elegant in my opinion if you have less conditions (<3) if to go for is else - and shorter ternary operators